# Git: Merging only branch specific commits

Tags: git, repository, git-merge, branching-and-merging

To give you a background the way I monitor `Git` repository and branches;

I have been monitoring two branches starting from each sprint - release and master. `Master` branch is from where developers create new branch(task specific), implement their changes, and creates pull request which gets merged into the `Master`. `Release` branch is sprint specific which remains always submittable to the production. We only merge branches committed to the Master and verified by the QA into Release branch. Makes sense? This approach works best when you want to submit release at fix regular interval with specific functionality implemented and verified, and hence you exactly know what's going in the next release.

It's going great until I run into following issue;

1. DeveloperA has created task specific branch say `taskA` from `Master`.
2. He has committed multiple times to `taskA` branch.
3. Mean while other developerB created his branch `taskB` from Master and committed multiple changes to the taskB and got taskB merged into `Master`.
4. DeveloperA will merge Master into `taskA` branch and further carry on his task!
5. Eventually he will get taskA branch merged into Master.

Now I just want to merge `taskA` branch to Release branch but as `taskB` was also merged into `taskA` branch, I get taskB branch changes automatically into Release branch! I don't want that. I know I can cherrypick all commits from `taskA` which becomes annoying.

Can someone please help me what's the best way to get only taskA branch changes to Release no matter if developer merged Master intermittently. Am I following wrong `Git` practice?

Comment: Why can't you simply merge `taskA` directly to `Release`?

Comment: because it also contains taskB branch changes as developer had merged it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the developer of the `taskA` branch (let's call him developer A) should [rebase](http://git-scm.com/book/be/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) his branch on the latest Release before creating a pull request (or merging it). Developer A should run this command prior to merging or creating a pull request:

```
git rebase -i origin/Release
```

This will give him an editor in which he can set what commits he wants to "pick"/use to be applied to his branch. If any commits from the `taskB` branch ended up in his branch, he can drop the commits of `taskB` if they are not ready for Release yet (just remove the lines containing those commits).

That way, all changes that have occurred in the Release branch in the meantime will be fetched and applied to his `taskA` branch. And then all commits that Developer A selected in the editor will be applied on top of that again. That way, the timeline is still correct and there should be no conflict whatsoever.

Comment: Thanks @Oldskool! We do not allow developers to merge anything to the Release branch. I am the only responsible for doing it so I keep track of what's going in the Release. Developers always create pull request to be merged in Master. As I have taskA branch, I think I can run the command you have given to merge only taskA branch changes to Release and see how it goes!