# Git Development vs Release branch best practices

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I have been monitoring two branches starting from each sprint - `Release` and `Master`.

`Master` branch is from where developers create new branch(task specific), implement their changes, and creates pull request which gets merged into the Master.

`Release` branch is sprint specific which remains always submittable to the production. We only merge branches committed to the `Master` and verified by the `QA` into Release branch.

This approach works best for us as we submit `Release` at fix regular interval with specific functionality implemented and verified, and hence we exactly know what's going in the next release.

This question is continuation of [avoid-merging-master-into-development-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29335603/avoid-merging-master-into-development-branch)
and [git-merging-only-branch-specific-commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742412/git-merging-only-branch-specific-commits)

In one line I want to

**"Make sure that only development branches which are verified by QA goes to the next Release Candidate."**

I have thought of to use following workflow options from my previous discussions;

> ```
> git pull --rebase master taskA
> //Work on taskA branch, do multiple commits, and also execute this command multiple times whenever required;
> At time of Rebasing taskA to Master
> git checkout taskA
> git rebase -i origin/Master // Remove any commits that are not belongs to taskA.
> git checkout origin/master
> git merge taskA
> ```

This workflow will give me clear history for each of my branches rebased on the `Master` which will be verified by QAs. I can easily rebase verified branch back to the `Release` branch.

Am I going in right direction? Would this git-flow works best? Is there any better way of doing what I want to achieve?

Comment: It's not obvious how your working with individual tasks (your command sequence example) is related to your goal of making sure only tested code goes into the release, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: As the last step I would suggest `git merge --no-ff taskA`. That way the range of commits that belong to the development of `taskA` are still visually close. This is helpful if you need to find a bug that has been introduced with `taskA`.

Comment: @MagnusBäck to make my goal possible, I have to make sure that I have clear separation of individual development branches so I can merge only verified branches to the Release. If I don't do it then I will ran into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742412/git-merging-only-branch-specific-commits problem

Comment: But task branches aren't merged directly to the release, they're merged to master, right? And release branches are cut from master? Your other question describes the problem when you're merging from task (feature) branches into the release branches, and that is indeed a problematic workflow.

Comment: Yes, so can you please suggest something to achieve my goal to "Make sure that only development branches which are verified by QA goes to the next Release Candidate."? I don't want to verify individual branches from QA and then merge to Master as it's getting to much annoying and testers have to test things again when development branch merged to Master!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's your problem.

> We only merge branches committed to the Master and verified by the QA into Release branch.

This means you have to integrate feature branches *twice*.  Once into Master and again into Release.  You're struggling with the obvious problem: how do you make sure everything integrated into Master is integrated into Release? And because features build on other features, they have to be in a similar order.

*Don't try to solve this problem*.  It's hard and messy and you'll always have to be careful.  Better to have a process that's more foolproof.  Let's go back to your stated goal.

> Make sure that *only development branches which are verified by QA* goes to the next Release Candidate.

(Emphasis mine) That's not really a goal, that's a solution to implement a goal.  What's your real goal?  How about this...

> Make sure that *only code which has been verified by QA* goes to the next Release.

See what I did there?  A quality release doesn't care about where the code came from, its cares about the state of the code being released.  You want to make sure nothing that hasn't been checked by QA goes into the release.  To do that, I would suggest changing your workflow to a version of the [Gitflow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow).  It goes like this.

1. Developer has a task to do.
2. Developer branches off `master`, let's call it `task`.
3. Developer works on `task`.

   1. Developer writes their own unit tests for the `task`.
4. Developer gets updates from `master` when they need them.

   1. They can rebase or they can merge, doesn't matter.
5. Developer finishes `task`.

   1. Developer does a final update from `master`.
   2. Developer makes sure their unit tests and all regression tests pass.
   3. *Optional* Developer submits the `task` to QA for acceptance testing.
   4. Developer merges into `master`.
   5. Developer deletes `task`.

Because developers are writing their own unit tests, at this point you know everything in `master` has been unit and integration tested.  Some important or hairy features have been acceptance tested in 5.3, but generally you don't bother QA with that at this point.

It is very important to a healthy workflow that `master` is always kept in a state of high quality.  This means developers have to be involved in the testing process.  There's no throwing it over the wall to QA and hoping for the best, QA should be spending their time on acceptance and blackbox testing to catch bugs the developers will not think of.  *Master is always your Release Candidate*.

When you decide you're ready for a release...

1. Match the `testing` branch to `master`.

   1. You can merge with `master`, rebase on `master` or delete and recreate the `testing` branch.  They each have slight advantages and disadvantages which will become apparent.
2. QA gets a list of all changes which have been added since the last release.

   1. They can get this from the issue tracker.
   2. If `testing` is rebased off `master` they can `git log` and look at the merge commits since the last release.
3. Have QA acceptance test the change list against `testing`.

Let's pause here and explain why step 3 is important.  QA is the final line before users see it.  It's important that QA is testing what the users will actually use.  Users will see the integrated code base, not individual feature branches working in isolation, so QA should focus their efforts on the integrated release.

Features can work great in isolation, and have weird bugs when they're combined.  A simple example would be a feature which changes the project's encoding from ASCII to Unicode.  The developer dutifully changes the whole system to use Unicode and it's great.  Meanwhile another developer works on a task which includes changing some views.  They're not thinking about character encoding, and they write their views with ASCII assumptions.  Developers are horrible about testing views.  Tested in isolation, but feature branches work fine.  Combined together, QA can catch the view which is still using the wrong character encoding.

Moving on.

4. QA finds bugs and reports them back to the developers.

   1. Developers patch `testing` (directly for small things, in a branch for big things)
   2. *Optional* Developers cherry-pick those fixes back to `master`.  It's optional because it will be taken care of later.
5. QA declares `testing` ready for release.

   1. `release` is `git merge --ff-only testing`.  If it doesn't fast-forward, you have hotfixes in `release` which need to be backported.
   2. Tag `release` with a version number.
   3. `release` is pushed to production.
6. `testing` is merged back into `master`.

That final step ensures any patches to bugs found in the QA process will be merged back into `master`.  This is why I said earlier it doesn't really matter how you reset `testing`, it will all be merged back into `master` anyway.

There you have it.  A process for ensuring all code which is released has gone through QA.  Except for developing the change log for QA, there is no careful tracking of what's been integrated where necessary.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern for taking time. I will rethink over our process.